# Jquery AjaxForm Unexpected token function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a beginner web developer and currently working on a jQuery where I have to send a form through AJAX. I don't understand well it's syntax atm and I think I did something wrong because I got

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

on line 2.

Any suggestion what did I do wrong? Here is the js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.simple-checkout').ajaxForm function (data)( {

}({
    success = function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        //alert("Termék a kosárba helyezve");
    },
    error = function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert("Hiba történt!");
    }
});
if (data.success){
    $("span.cart-value").load(" span.cart-value");
}
```

});

I have to reload the `span.cart-value` if the `ajaxForm` returns with success.

Comment: You're missing `(`.

Comment: `.ajaxForm function (data)(` <= it's dare